# How to Export Private / Secret ASC Key to Decrypt GPG Files

Tags: encryption, gnu, gnupg, private-key

Background: My boss has tried exporting an ASC key to me with public and private parts but whenever I get the file the private part never loads up and it won't decrypt any files.

We have tried Exporting the ASC Key using:

- Windows Application Kleopatra 2.1 (included in gpg4win)
- Windows Application GNU Privacy Assistant (included in gpg4win)

  ```
  Error: "Decryption failed. Secret Key Not available."
  ```

How do you properly export a secret or private asc key to decrypt gpg files?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You can export the private key with the [command-line tool from GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/download/). It works on the Windows-shell. Use the following command:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys
```

A normal export with `--export` will not include any private keys, therefore you have to use `--export-secret-keys`.

Edit:

To sum up the information given in my comments, this is the command that allows you to export a specific key with the ID 1234ABCD to the file secret.asc:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor 1234ABCD > secret.asc
```

You can find the ID that you need using the following command. The ID is the second part of the second column:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

To Export just 1 specific secret key instead of all of them:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys keyIDNumber > exportedKeyFilename.asc
```

keyIDNumber is the number of the key id for the desired key you are trying to export.

Comment: @Brian: This will dump the key to the console. If you want to store it in a file, you can redirect the output to an arbitrary filename ("gpg --export-secret-keys > secret.asc").

Comment: @Brian: This gives you the output in ASCII and not in binary. If you keep it in a file, it doesn't really matter. But once you want to pass it around any other way, the ASCII version is much easier to handle (sending it inline in an email e.g.)

Comment: Maybe you want to carry your secret key to another location. In this case you should encrypt the exported data: "gpg --export-secret-keys keyIDNumber | gpg -c >encrypted"
decrypt it with "gpg -o unencrypted encrypted".

Comment: Doesn't the first example do the same thing as the second one? I mean, 1234ABCD seems to refer to a single secret key, does it not? However, you imply that it encompasses all of them, somehow. Also, do we get the key ID from the pub or sub row?

Comment: Keys exported from GnuPG remain encrypted (which is why you don't need to enter the private key passphrase), so there's really no need to encrypt it again.

Comment: I'm getting `error receiving key from agent: Permission denied - skipped` on `--export-secret-keys -a [myid]`

Comment: According to `man gpg` use of the option `--armor` with `--export-secret-keys` is intended for creating paper backups and "presents a security risk" if sent over an insecure channel.

Comment: @FerryBoender [Are you sure about that](https://www.jabberwocky.com/software/paperkey/)?

Comment: According to paper copy:
>  If your key has a passphrase on it (i.e. is encrypted), the paper copy is similarly encrypted
Although I have yet to find this in the official GPG doc.

Also opened an issue on a gpg yubikey guide https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide/issues/195

Comment: The difference between whether has '--armor' option is whether the output is in ascii format. The output is in readable ascii format if '--armor' is added.

Comment: Don't we rather want to use `gpg --list-secret-keys` to filter out the noise of the public keys we might also have?

Answer (score 34):

All the above replies are correct, but might be missing one crucial step, you need to edit the imported key and "ultimately trust" that key

```
gpg --edit-key (keyIDNumber)
gpg> trust

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu
```

and select 5 to enable that imported private key as one of your keys

Answer (score 21):

See the treatment by Dark Otter

https://montemazuma.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/moving-a-gpg-key-privately/

If the site is down use reference the archive.org backup:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170518155052/https://montemazuma.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/moving-a-gpg-key-privately/

which includes a reasonably secure way to transfer keys. You could put that recommendation into shell-scripts shown below for repeated use.

First get the KEYID you want from the list shown by

```
$ gpg -K
```

From the resulting list note the KEYID (the 8 hexadecimals following sec) you need for transfer.

Then envoke the tested shell scipts "export_private_key" on the first account and generate your pubkey.gpg + keys.asc. Subsequently invoke on the second account "import_private_key". Here is their content shown with cat (copy & paste content):

```
$ cat export_private_key 
gpg -K
echo "select private key"
read KEYID
gpg --output pubkey.gpg --export $KEYID
echo REMEMBER THE COMING PASS-PHRASE
gpg --output - --export-secret-key $KEYID | \
   cat pubkey.gpg - | \
   gpg --armor --output keys.asc --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256
ls -l pubkey.gpg keys.asc
####################  E X P O R T _ P R I V A T E _ K E Y  #####################
```

Now tranfer by some means the "pubkey.gpg" (if needed) and the private "keys.asc" to the second account and envoke the below-shown program.

```
$ cat import_private_key 
gpg --no-use-agent --output - keys.asc | gpg --import
###################  I M P O R T _ P R I V A T E _ K E Y  ######################
```

In Otter's spirit "And that, should be, that".

Comment: Thank you for the script to include both the public and private key in one passphrase-protected file. Makes my life much better!

Comment: Option `--no-use-agent` is obsolete in gpg version 2.

Answer (score 10):

I think you had not yet import the private key as the message error said, To import public/private key from gnupg:

```
gpg --import mypub_key
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import myprv_key
```

Comment: i was asking about exporting from a computer that works... you can only import the key if its on a local server.

Comment: @Brian McCarthy: What are you trying to say?

Comment: Do we really need to import the public key if the private one has been imported already? As I understand, a public key can be generated out of a private one anything.

Comment: @farhany I think yes, because you will need it when you sign your message.

Answer (score 6):

this ended up working for me:

```
gpg -a --export-secret-keys > exportedKeyFilename.asc
```

you can name keyfilename.asc by any name as long as you keep on the .asc extension.
this command copies all secret-keys on a user's computer to keyfilename.asc in the working directory of where the command was called.

To Export just 1 specific secret key instead of all of them:

```
gpg -a --export-secret-keys keyIDNumber > exportedKeyFilename.asc
```

keyIDNumber is the number of the key id for the desired key you are trying to export.

Comment: You can list all available keys with "--list-keys". The second column will contain IDs like "2048g/1234ABCD". Find the desired key and export it with "gpg --export-secret-keys 1234ABCD > secret.asc", of course changing 1234ABCD with the correct ID.

You can also add the "-a" flag. It writes the output with ASCII characters, just in case the binary output is causing trouble.

Comment: @demento, thanks for the additional feedback... ill add that to the answer

Comment: you still need the -a if you really want asc

Comment: How do you then import them to another computer?

Comment: @Natim I imagine you take `exportedKeyFilename.asc` to the other computer and then do `gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import exportedKeyFilename.asc` in the directory with the `.asc` file. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184947/how-to-import-secret-gpg-key-copied-from-one-machine-to-another

Comment: You may want to export using --cipher-algo AES256 --symmetric. See http://superuser.com/questions/633715/how-do-i-fix-warning-message-was-not-integrity-protected-when-using-gpg-symme

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @Wolfram J's answer, here is a method to encrypt your private key [with a passphrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm):

```
gpg --output - --armor --export $KEYID | \
    gpg --output private_key.asc --armor --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256
```

And a corresponding method to decrypt:

```
gpg private_key.asc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if your key was passphrased initially.
I filed an issue about it:
https://github.com/open-keychain/open-keychain/issues/2723

Answer (score 5):

1.Export a Secret Key (this is what your boss should have done for you)

```
gpg --export-secret-keys yourKeyName > privateKey.asc
```

2.Import Secret Key (import your privateKey)

```
gpg --import privateKey.asc
```

3.Not done yet, you still need to ultimately trust a key.
You will need to make sure that you also ultimately trust a key.

```
gpg --edit-key yourKeyName
```

Enter trust, 5, y, and then quit

Source: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/public-key-asymmetric-cryptography-using-gpg-5a8d914c9bca